# PS3 Controller not charging or syncing with ps3

Tags: ps3, controllers

The last time i played a game on my playstation 3 was in February 2014. Now, its August 2014, and my controller can't seem to sync with my PS3 Console.

Whenever I connect it using the charging cord, nothing happens, and when I press the round button, it syncs with the console, but doesn't blink (*i.e doesn't charge*). And as soon as I disc my charging cord with the PS3, it loses the connection. Its like a ps2 controller, whenever I connect. one light turns on but doesn't blink.

I won't charge on my pc as well. I am running windows 8.1 and i tried everything i read online but nothing happened! Also tried pressing the reset button but no luck! Its been two days now.

Comment: Does the controller do anything when it's plugged in? You indicated that a direct connection it syncs with the console (which is not what you're saying in the rest of the question)

Comment: when i connect the cable and press the button it the centre. It syncs. But doesnt charge i.e blink! And when i disconnect the charging wire from the controller, it loses the connection i.e all lights turn off! The charge level on my controller is - even when it is connected via charging cable!

Comment: Can you navigate through menus when it's plugged in? Sorry I didn't make the question more clear.

Comment: yes, it can!!!!

Comment: Related Question: [Is it normal for PS3 controllers to constantly lose their charge?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/113771/28182)

Answer (score 2):

Boot to main menu, plug the controller in charging cord, sync controller with console, and then press *and hold* the PS button for few seconds, the console should show you controller menu, showing charge level as well. If it shows "--" instead of charge level (bars inside battery icon) then that means that battery in controller is dead.

Comment: Yes. You're right. It shows '-' when I hold the PlayStation button.

Comment: @AhmadGhauri well then, you need either replacement battery or just a new controller. However if it's less than a year after purchase you are eligible for a free warranty replacement.

Comment: Once my controller started charging via my laptop's USB port. And it never stopped charging. All 4 lights kept blinking for like 6 hours and they never stopped. I disconnected and pressed the round button but nothing happened. No flashing lights, nothing. I think i'll go for a new controller. Been using this for almost two years now

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the battery inside the controller may be dead. You can unscrew the back and swap out the battery with another controller to test it out. It could also be a loose connector inside the controller as well.

Comment: Okay. I think I'll buy a new controller. Its been 3 years since I had this and I think its natural that after so much use and charging of controller the battery died... Guess it's time to buy me a new one.

Comment: My X button died after about 4 years of use. Everything goes through wear and tear sadly.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate suggestion, I might have you try different USB cables. In my experience the PS3 is very picky about cable quality and cheap cables will not support charging and in some cases, the controller wouldn't even be detected.

I ran into this myself and thought I was loosing my mind with four controllers and a cheep cable and trying to use a cheaply made cable, then I tried a higher quality cable and everything worked great. I'm not talking about overprice Monster cables or anything. Just something that actually us using a decent grade wire, and not the kind of cable you get for $1.

Comment: I tried that. Used the original cable which cane along with my console as well as the I have for my PSP.. Tried them both but no luck. Once my controller started charging via my laptop's USB port. And it never stopped charging. All 4 lights kept blinking for like 6 hours and they never stopped. I disconnected and pressed the round button but nothing happened. It didn't even blink after 6 hours of flashing.